# Efficient bit-testing conditional iteration over distinct array-elements

Tags: python, numpy, iteration

I have two 2D-numpy arrays of equal shape, one containing data, and one of type `'ubyte'` storing bitflags per pixel. I want to visit every pixel in the data-array that has a particular flag in the bitflags-array.

I could just iterate over every pixel in either array and use the multi-index to get the bitflags and the value of the pixel, e.g.

```
it = np.nditer(array, flags=['multi_index'])
while not it.finished:
    if bitflags[it.multi_index] & FLAG:
        do_something(array[it.multi_index])
    it.iternext()
```

Since most pixels do not have the corresponding bitflag set, I would rather like to find all pixels with the given bitflag (for example using `numpy.where(bitflags & FLAG)` and iterate only over these pixels - something like

```
pixels = np.where(bitflags & FLAG)
for pixel in array[pixels]:
    do_something()
```

Is there a way I can still get the indices of the original array to use them in `do_something()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not completely sure if I understand your question correctly, but are you looking for this:

```
pixels, = np.where(bitflags & FLAG)
for i, pixel in zip(pixels, array[pixels]):
    do_something(i, pixel)
```

Comment: Such an easy solution! Thank you!
Since my arrays are two-dimensional, `len(pixels)` is 2, so your code does not work directly, but I can get the actual indices using

`p,y,x in zip(array[pixels], *pixels)`

I totally missed this, since I rarely need `zip`